# node.js discord.js cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (message.content.startsWith("-send")) {
    if (message.author.id === '405714654065721344') {
        var text = message.content.substring(6)
        db.serialize();
        db.all(`SELECT log_channel FROM log_value`, function (err, rows) {
            if (!err) {
                rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    message.channel.send(row.log_channel)
                    let channel_id = row.log_channel;
                    console.log(channel_id)
                    parseInt(channel_id)
                    try {
                        bot.channels.get(`'${channel_id}`).send(text)
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    } else {
        return error.noPerms(message, "BOT DEVELOPS", message.author.username)
    }
}
```

I want my bot (public) can sendMessage in specific channel. 
but I have an error.

> error: cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in `` bot.channels.get(`'${channel_id}`).send(text) `` is not how [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) work.

```js
bot.channels.get(channel_id).send(text)
```

should work.

Comment: Then I would check if `channel_id` (or `row.log_channel`) is actually definited. It also does make sense to give the exact line the error gets thrown, since there are more than one positions where you try to send something.